# Return SQL Query with XML as a single flattened row

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008R2 or 2012

Is it possible to return an XML nodes query as a single row instead of multiple rows where each returned item is a new column instead of a row?

For example, the XML field contains the following XML structure:

```
<MetaFieldData>
  <MetaField>
    <Name>Volume</Name>
    <Value>Large</Value>
  </MetaField>
  <MetaField>
    <Name>Code</Name>
    <Value>3DP</Value>
  </MetaField>
  <MetaField>
    <Name>Photo</Name>
    <Value>foo.png</Value>
  </MetaField>
  <MetaField>
    <Name>CommonName</Name>
    <Value>Foo Bar</Value>
  </MetaField>
</MetaFieldData>
```

With the following SQL:

```
select 
    m.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name,
    m.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Value
from MyTable 
cross apply MetaFieldData.nodes('/MetaFieldData/MetaField') as Meta(m)
where Id = 1
```

The result set will return:

```
Name        Value
--------------------
Volume      Large
Code        3DP
Photo       foo.png
CommonName  Foo Bar
```

How would you return the result set as:

```
Volume     Code     Photo     CommonName
----------------------------------------------
Large      3DP      foo.png   Foo Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Volume,Code,Photo,CommonName
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        m.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Name,
        m.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Value
    FROM MyTable 
    CROSS APPLY MetaFieldData.nodes('/MetaFieldData/MetaField') as Meta(m)
    WHERE Id = 1
) P
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value) FOR Name IN (Volume,Code,Photo,CommonName)
) pvt
```